# How to control for other (demographic variables) when using regression in STATA?

Tags: regression, data-analysis, stata, readstata13

I want to use regression analysis to find out whether attending English Tutoring Schools make a difference for IELT Text takers, controlling for demographics factors like age, gender, salary...
This is what I want:
Regression 1: first test score of each individual as dependent variable
Regression 2: last test score of each individual as dependent variable

This is what I have so far(attached in image) but I'm not sure if I've done it right.
[Please check this for the commands I've used so far](https://i.stack.imgur.com/57t2h.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.